# Hidden field loses value in codebehind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to pass data from my client to server using a HiddenField.

Javascript/UI.ascx

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="PassArgs" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>
//Tried using EnableViewState, but still no luck


<script>

document.getElementById("<%=PassArgs.ClientID%>").value = JSON.stringify(SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args());
alert(document.getElementById("<%=PassArgs.ClientID%>").value); 
//Alert shows correct data to be passed

</script>
```

However when I try to access my HiddenField from the codebehind, my result is empty.

CodeBehind

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(PassArgs.Value);
//PassArgs.Value = ""     --- whyyyy???
```

I am posting this question as a last resort because I have spent a full work day looking at similar questions, but I am not able to get this to work for my situation.

How come my alert of 'PassArgs' contains the correct values, but my code behind shows empty? I have tried using HiddenFields, TextBoxes, and Labels, but the result is the same for all of them.

EDIT: The HiddenField seems to have the correct values when the script is run, I dont think thats the problem, but I think the script is running AFTER iv already tried to access it in the codebehind. I think that may be why the HiddenField is showing empty, because the script hasent run yet.  How can I get this to run in UI.ascx before my debugger gets to the codebehind (UI.ascx.cs) to access it?

Comment: Do you reset `PassArgs` somewhere in code-behind? For example, in the `Load` event handler of the page.

Comment: @ConnorsFan No, It does not get set anywhere else besides the javascript

Comment: @Reeggiie when are you reading the value in code behind? After a button press or something similar? Because the value of the hiddenfield needs to be posted to the server first.

Comment: @VDWWD Yes, after a button click

Comment: Any `UpdatePanel` in your form?

Comment: @ConnorsFan No, I am not using an UpdatePanel

Comment: Use JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest` to send data to the server. Don't use UpdatePanel.

Comment: @VDWWD It is after a button click. How do I ensure the value is posted to the server first?

Comment: @Reeggiie, that is what a button click should be doing. Set breakpoints and see if you receive data in code behind or that the hiddenfield is posted empty.

Comment: You can make a test: put another hidden field in the form, with a different ID, give it a simple value in Javascript code, and see if it is posted back correctly.

Comment: @Reeggiie Try with: `document.getElementById("<%=PassArgs.ClientID%>").setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args());`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez This also contains the values, but its still blank in the code behind. I believe the script is running AFTER I try to access the Hiddenfield, which is why its blank. I am trying to figure out how to get it to run before the codebehind.

Comment: @Reeggiie I can't see any button in your code. Can you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch data from server variables, so you can get the value by calling `Request.Form["PassArgs"]` which returns the value of your request , and you can parse the result of the request collection of your form `Convert.ToString(Request.Form)` as well

otherwise you can use the TextBox field with a hidden style in case it is still not working

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PassArgs" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried both of these ways, and my code behind still retrieves null.